# Maximize RAID1 efficiency when using usb 2.0 and usb 3.0 interfaces

Tags: arch-linux, performance, raspbian, raid1

I have available a single USB 2.0 port and a single USB 3.0 port and would like to set up two HDDs (both USB 3.0) in RAID1.

Not entirely sure how mirroring works, but was wondering if there was some way I could configure the drive connected to the USB 3.0 port to serve as a 'primary' drive of sorts that would be prioritized for 'initial' writes/reads in order to maximize performance, with any data being copied to the drive connected to the USB 2.0 interface.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome. Ideally the solution would work for an OS compatible with the raspberry pi 4, however, I would be interested to learn of any other solutions as well.

Comment: The reading speed limit imposed by USB 2 caps out at about 8 MB/sec for USB2, and 20 MB/sec for USB3; writes will be worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have a hardware limitation with 2 separate USB technologies:

- [USB2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0) has a maximum signalling rate of 480Mbps
- [USB3.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.x) has a maximum signalling rate of 5120Mbps (5.0 Gbps)

setting up the RAID-1 using [`mdadm`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) (*`m`ulti `d`evice `adm`inistrator*) will have some draw-backs.

#### Option 1: Add hardware.

Add a USB 3.x port splitter / USB 3.x HUB and connect both HDDs to the HUB and the HUB to the USB 3.x port of the Pi therefore lowering their individual maximum theoretical transfer rate to 2560 Mbps (5120/2) instead of hooking one up to the USB2 port and the other to the USB3 as that would lower the maximum theoretical transfer rate ***of both*** to just 480Mbps.¹

#### Option 2: Live with *some* difference in speed.²

OK, so you don't have the time, money nor physical space to put a USB HUB and a Pi and 2 HDDs in this solution:
As there is no such thing as "Primary"  and "Secondary" in RAID (any version) but only [JBOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-RAID_drive_architectures#JBOD) combined into one, you could use the `write-mostly` option of `mdadm` to circumvent *some* of the disparities.

This option will designate one of the HDDs as "slow" and all reads will come from the fast one *but all writes will still wait for the slow one*. (so only half of the benefits of the USB 3.0 disk)

#### Setting up the RAID:

All following commands need to be executed as `root` or with `sudo`.

Let's suppose that the first HDD comes up as `/dev/sdc` and the second one as `/dev/sdd` execute the following command to create a software RAID called `md0` with RAID Level 1 using 2 HDDs:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

***Only if you use option #2***, you should add `--write-mostly` *before the slow drive* (`sdd` taken as example) and use the following command instead of the one above (hover over it with your mouse to unhide it to avoid any confusing which to use):

> mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc --write-mostly /dev/sdd

Now we have to create a file system on the newly created `/dev/md0` software RAID:

```
mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0
```

Now we're going to mount this space in `/mnt` (substitute this if you need to mount this somewhere else)

```
mkdir --parents /mnt/md0
```

And edit your `fstab` to include this mount at every boot (add the second line at the end of your `fstab`):

```
nano /etc/fstab
/dev/md0  /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults 0 2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit.

Now reboot to make it active or type to following command without rebooting:

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/md0
```

<sub>**Note 1:** The weakest link in the chain dictates the overall speed as 2 HDDs become one.  **:-(**</sub>
<sub>**Note 2:** Thanks to [fra-san](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/315749/fra-san) and [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) for [pointing me in the right direction](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51286102#51286102) for the second option!</sub>
<sub>**Note 3:** For more info on `mdadm` type `man mdadm` on the pi itself and read it (all of it even the stuff you think you'll never need like re-assembling RAIDs after a fail...) **;-)**</sub>
**Note 4: A RAID is not a substiture for backups! ;-P**

Comment: (hi! Fabby) Using USB for hard disks or even wifi is never as stable or comparable to having them via other SATA/PCI/whatever.  USB does not scale and does not sustain high speeds for long. The point of doing RAID over USB is...strange. I got myself a ARM board with a SATA interface in the SoC, when had the need for doing some backups in a cheap medium.

Comment: I agree @RuiFRibeiro but it's what OP wants, so let's give him the best we can do.